# Why do I have to use [el as type] to access a value in a Record?

Tags: typescript

Why do I have to use the code `return DNAtoRNA[el as DNA]` to access the value of a Record? and why do I get a linting error when I try to access it using `DNAtoRNA[el]`?

Also, I was given to believe a Record in TS was similar to Map in JS? If so, why can I not use the get method to retrieve a value?

Thanks!

```
type DNA = 'G' | 'C' | 'T' | 'A';
type RNA = 'C' | 'G' | 'A' | 'U';

const DNAtoRNA: Record<DNA, RNA> = {
    'G': 'C',
    'C': 'G',
    'T': 'A',
    'A': 'U'
};

class Transcriptor {
    toRna(dna: string) {
        //const formatInputToArr: string[] = dna.split('');
        const translateDnaToRna = dna.split('').map(el => {
            return DNAtoRNA[el as DNA]
        })

        console.log(translateDnaToRna);

        if (translateDnaToRna.includes(undefined)) {
            throw new Error('Invalid input DNA.');
        } else {
            return translateDnaToRna.join('');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `Record` is simply an object. The first type argument is the type of the keys, and the second is the type of the values. It's *like* a `Map` in the same way a plain object is like a `Map`, they both have a value for each of a set of keys.

If you want an actual `Map`, with the api of a `Map`, you need to actually use and instantiate a `Map`.

```
const DNAtoRNA: Map<DNA, RNA> = new Map()
DNAtoRNA.set('G', 'C')
DNAtoRNA.get('G') // 'C'
```

---

But let's keep this as `Record` type objects.

The error your getting here is:

```
return DNAtoRNA[el]
// Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type
//   'string' can't be used to index type 'Record<DNA, RNA>'.
```

`DNA` is a more specific type than string. And `Record<DNA, RNA>` only guarantees that there is a value for keys in `DNA`, not any string.

But `el` here is of type `string`, not `DNA`. Typescript is warning you that you may have a bug, and you might be accessing `DNAtoRNA` by an invalid key.

The typesafe way to fix this is with a typeguard which does a runtime check to assert that `el` is a safe value to use.

```
function isDNA(nucleotide: string): nucleotide is DNA {
    return ['G', 'C', 'T', 'A'].includes(nucleotide)
}
```

Now you can check each nucleotide before you use it to index your record:

```
const translateDnaToRna = dna.split('').map(el => {
    if (isDNA(el)) {
        return DNAtoRNA[el]
    } else {
        throw new Error("bad data")
    }
})
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?jsx=2&ssl=17&ssc=9&pln=18&pc=9#code/C4TwDgpgBAIgcgQSgXigcgOJqgH3QYWzzQBUj0E0BuAKFEigCVEUDzN3Ld0BVammgGMA9gDsAzsFiJgw5ggBcTCCIBOAEwA88BABomiAHysA3jSgX0WJWkK7zl22htZ7l9GRuU3jyjb40AL60NABmAK6igsAAlmJQMeI6ABSi4YIANhDCseoQSpKqMaIA5gCUSmmZ2bnQidJIZu6qEMDhqqJQANoc+k59ZH2UALoAdMWZ4XniqelZOTF5ZUECmQCG4uJQJKprEoJFYLKqUE2Wsoyia8nqVwXARaVlpw7uFiISUg974hlrwBAYFcSHIrqxbmtRuIwBkYsBkmg0GVRgBbNZgZIQDIoYxnN5vGKhKDJRIpLFlZ54-HUlptDoNC6ILpY4avakWQJQLHiaBU9nuYAAC1UwgA7lBRBBxQBRVQi1TJABEACM1uooOp-mtFct+ZZAmz3IFlobLB9xMIsqMMsISslvhI-gCgWsQZc1mUQuzCcSHb9-oDgaDIRMMlMIDNInlQsUIOoKS89RYhSLxZKZXLhAq0ABJUQANzWsPVxTA4SkOlGSNo7M53N5pvxtPanT9TsDruDowAVsJigjq42oAajUEgA)
(ignore the type errrors for `.includes` is the playground standard library doesn't have that function defined)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your thorough response - was very helpful. Regarding the ```el as dna``` statement, so that is basically saying ```find the index of el in the record with a type of DNA```? is that the best way to think of it?

Comment: No. `as` it's a type cast. That's saying that you the programmer know more about this variables than typescript can infer. `el as DNA` says that even though `el` is a `string`, you the programmer can assert that `el` is actually the subtype of string `DNA`. And typescript takes your word for it whether you are correct or not. But in this case, if your `dna` contained characters that weren't allowed, the cast would not be correct, and you could have runtime bugs. That's why the type guard function is good here, because you are actually testing if each character is the right type.